# How to get user local time zone in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, timezone

I wanna get the local time zone in typescript in form of *'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'*. Is there any ways to get the correct time zone.

note: when i try something like **'Asia/Tokyo'**, I can get time zone in tokyo, but i can't find the code to give me the corect time zone without setting the specific time zone code like 'Asia/Tokyo' above.

Comment: try momentjs...

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1091372/2050306